# What did it mean to be a renaissance man?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

A renaissance man is a person whose interest is in everything.

According to [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Renaissance-man) it is a

> notion expressed by one of its most accomplished representatives, Leon Battista Alberti (1404–72), that “a man can do all things if he will.” The ideal embodied the basic tenets of Renaissance Humanism, which considered man the centre of the universe, limitless in his capacities for development, and led to the notion that men should try to embrace all knowledge and develop their own capacities as fully as possible.

And given these guidelines, can the idea still live on today in the echoes of other philosophies? If so what do other philosophers have to say about being a renaissance man?

For those who want an overview of famous renaissance men, they can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Renaissance_figures)

Comment: "Guidelines " ????

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA a Renaissance man is a person whose interest(s) are in all things. I've edited the question to more fully flesh out the idea